# Date time values incorrect on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know where the problem is within my code. I am trying to insert a value from datetime picker. But as it's saved into the MySQL database, the date value is 1970-01-01.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $FirstName=$_POST['fname'];
    $LastName=$_POST['lname'];
    $AreaCode=$_POST['acode'];
    $PrimaryPhone=$_POST['pphone'];
    $AlternatePhone=$_POST['aphone'];
    $EmailAddress=$_POST['email'];
    $CompanyName=$_POST['cname'];
    $StreetAddress=$_POST['saddress'];
    $BrgyCityProvince=$_POST['province'];
    $ZipCode=$_POST['zcode'];
    $rdate= "rawdate";
    $cdate= strtr($rdate, '/', '-');
    $Date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cdate));


    $sql = "Insert into bill values('','$FirstName','$LastName','$AreaCode','$PrimaryPhone','$AlternatePhone','$EmailAddress','$CompanyName','$StreetAddress','$BrgyCityProvince','$ZipCode', '$Date')";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$query)
        echo mysql_error();
    else
    {
        echo "Successfully inserted";
    }
?>
```

Comment: If your database table has a column set to date then use` date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $date ) );` else if it is a datetime columns use `date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $date ) );`  Edit: Also use lowercase `date`

Comment: no progress. i have tried yours but it doesn't change.

Comment: i have remove the quote on my variable but stilll nothing change. help!!

Comment: Show you whole code please, including the insert statement

Comment: You say `$rdate="rawdate"` but are you setting rawdate somewhere or are you trying to convert a string to a date?

Comment: rawdate is the value of the date time picker

Comment: Did you bother checking if strtotime succeeded? If it fails, it returns boolean false, which typecasts into integer 0 for `date`, and format as the epoch date, jan 1/1970

Answer (score 3):

Don't use quote around your variable in strtotime.

```
 $Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cdate));
```

Comment: I had solve it! I changed my code and found the solution through the internet. by the way thanks guys!